# subversion -- can't see or clear D flag

Tags: subversion

So I've got a two-part problem that I can't figure out.  I know I'm not supposed to ask two questions together, but I can't tell if they are related or not.

```
# ls -l lzp.xml
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user group   49341 Sep 19  2018 lzp.xml
# svn stat | grep lzp
# svn stat -v | grep lzp
D             6896     6209 username     lzp.xml
```

Why is this file, with the "to be deleted" flag active, not showing up in a standard `svn stat` command?

```
# svn revert lzp.xml
# svn stat -v | grep lzp
D             6896     6209 username     lzp.xml
```

Why is `revert` not clearing the `D` flag, and how can I clear it?

Comment: This might be a consequence of some interrupted action leaving your working copy inconsistent. I would suggest you to try `svn cleanup` before further resolving the issue

Comment: @Tagwint Thanks.  `svn cleanup` generated no output and did nothing obvious that I can see.

Comment: Perhaps you could get more info from following actions:
1. `svn st -vu`  (status respecting the server status) 2. make another working copy of this folder in some other folder and compare that to this one. 3. exec `svn log -v lzp.xml` in both working copies and compare the output